# Extend build of meteor with custom tasks

Tags: javascript, meteor, gruntjs

I have some custom script I'd like to run as part of the meteor build script, preferable within a certain step of the build process.
I am reasonable familiar with Maven, Ant and Makefile and Grunt but I can't figure out how to extend the build-process of Meteor.

There's some reference in the Documentation how to create a [build-plugin](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/Package-registerBuildPlugin), but I 'just' want to execute some (Java)script during the build. Another [so-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18443412/how-to-make-grunt-js-and-meteor-js-work-together) mentions using Grunt and run Meteor as part of the build but that sounds a bit backwards as Meteor seems to be a build-system already.

Does Meteor have a build-file hidden somewhere I can extend or modify?

Answer (score 1):

Since Meteor 1.2, there's an option to add your own Build Plugin. Get more info here: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Build-Plugins-API